# How to access MUI 5 theme variables in deep functional component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The MUI 5 docs on Theming have a section on "[Accessing the theme in a component](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component)". However, it's really just one sentence that links to the [legacy style docs](https://mui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component).

Here's the example they give in those legacy docs:

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/styles';

function DeepChild() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return <span>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</span>;
}
```

Which is pretty much exactly what I want to do — I want to be able to access the theme color palette down in some deep functional component. However, my component complains

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/styles' in...`

Digging a little further, it seems they're rather strongly trying to discourage people from using this legacy Styles technique, and the MUI 5 way to do this is with "[system design tokens](https://mui.com/system/basics/#design-tokens-in-the-theme)", which I guess should Just Work. But, they're not.

I have my whole app wrapped in `ThemeProvider`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import theme from './theme';
import Foo from './foo';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
        <Foo />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And then in `foo.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

export const Foo = () => {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        background: 'repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, '
          + ' theme.palette.error.light, theme.palette.error.light 25px,'
          + ' theme.palette.error.dark 25px, theme.palette.error.dark 50px'
          + ')',
      }}
    >
      <span>Test</span>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I initially started with just `error.light` and `error.dark`. When that didn't work, I expanded it all to `palette.error.light`, etc..., and then ultimately to `theme.palette.error.light`, etc....

It seems no matter what I try, it's not accessing those theme variables, and is instead just passing through the text.

So, back to the question: how am I supposed to access MUI 5 theme variables in nested functional components?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/styles';
```

with

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

`@mui/styles` is used for legacy, you can add it using `yarn add` or `npm install`, but first give a shot to what I mentioned above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).